# Adding an Angular debug build / application to IIS

Tags: angular, debugging, asp.net-core, deployment

I'd like to add an Angular application to local my `IIS`, so I can attach a debugger when required.

I'd use `ng serve` in the background and not have Visual Studio running IIS Express for debugging, although if it can serve Angular content as well that'd be a bonus.

This matches my older workflow for normal MVC (and other) projects. I can edit my server side code and rebuild without having to stop and start `IIS Express`, then attach to `w3wp` process whenever I need to drop into the server side code.

Any IIS guides I've found have all been for production builds.

.NET Core 3 solution essentially looks like this:

project.BusinessLayer (Class Library)
project.PresentationLayer (Angular Project with ClientAppF folder etc.)

Comment: Can't you just select IIS as target from properties of your project? Properties --> Debug... You need to run VS as administrator for this to work.

Comment: @monkeySeeMonkeyDo any luck on getting this working? Mine loads the site but IIS acts as if the site doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this one out.

[Install Development-time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for IIS, this will allow you to add an IIS target as mentioned by [DaggeJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6038796/daggej). For the lazy, the target is added via the project properties:

[image: iis target entry]

Adding the IIS target should automatically add the application to IIS. If this fails, simply add the application manually, it needs to be pointing to the root of the `Angular .NET project`, not the `ClientApp` folder.

Web Sockets need to be enabled for IIS, else hot loading will not work. This is achieved via `Turn windows features on or off`:

[image: windows features]

IIS will now serve the application, and hot loading will work.

There is one draw back to this, changing any backend code and rebuilding will require the Angular server to start again, this is a slow process and can get annoying fast.

To get around this:

- Add `spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");` to
  `Startup.cs`
- run `npm start` from the `ClientApp` folder (**not** `ng serve`)

This is the same result as before, expect now the application will load much quicker after rebuilding.

If you need to debug the backend, ctrl+altt+p and attach to the IIS process w3wp.exe. You can reattach the next time around with ctrl+shift+p.

Answer (score 2):

Try to build you angular app(not prod) and the keep that dist folder contents to some place in the system with IIS server and host that folder using IIS.
This way you will be able to host and debug your application

Comment: if I do a debug build, I get no dist folder. I get output to \obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1 which then contains my application. I think I need to read up on this some more as I am likely missing something obvious.

Comment: find the folder with index.html file

Comment: That folder doesn't contain the index file. It appears as if the application is built into an executable. That does remind me of seeing a web.config example somewhere that was referencing an executable in that output folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `ng build`, it will generate a dist folder which contains source map file (By default --sourcemap is set to true). You can directly use IIS host this dist folder as static content. It can be debug in browser.

I'm not sure what is the reason you want to host Angular app in local IIS instead of angular-cli's default web server (with run `ng serve`). In general, the frontend code & backend code are running indepedently. For front-end, usually people use `ng serve` to make it easy to run and debug, and connect to backend with adding a proxy.conf.json file.

.net Core Web application has an wwwroot folder which used for hosting static content, you can also put the build content there :)

Comment: As mentioned I am happy to run ng serve, that is what I am currently doing. The server running via  `ng serve` does not find the back end as it isn't running running until I run with IIS Express. I find this cumbersome, and rather have the back end constantly run via IIS and then attach the debugger as needed. I hope that makes more sense.